# How to automatically close PySimpleGUI popup?

Tags: python, multithreading, popup, pysimplegui

I'm working with PySimpleGUI and opening autoclosing popup, but it is not closing by itself, even when I press OK button. Only if I press 'X'
Here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import threading
import time

layout = [
    [sg.Text('', size=(40, 1))],
    [sg.Text('', size=(30, 2)), sg.Text('Press "Start" button', size=(55, 12), key='-MAIN-')],
    [sg.Button('Start', size=(10,2))],
]
window = sg.Window('APP', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Start':
        def thread_reminder(seconds):
            seconds = 0
            while True:
                seconds += 1
                time.sleep(1)
                print(seconds)
                if seconds == 10:
                    sg.popup_auto_close("1 minute passed")
        threading.Thread(target=thread_reminder, args=(1,), daemon=True).start()
window.close()
```

And this gives me this error or exception, I don't know:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/Downloads/jkl;'.py", line 23, in thread_reminder
    sg.popup_auto_close("1 minute passed")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 15782, in PopupAutoClose
    return Popup(*args, title=title, button_color=button_color, background_color=background_color, text_color=text_color,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 15353, in Popup
    button, values = window.read()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 7568, in Read
    results = self._read(timeout=timeout, timeout_key=timeout_key)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 7623, in _read
    self._Show()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 7395, in _Show
    StartupTK(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 12817, in StartupTK
    window.TKroot.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1420, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different apartment
*** Faking timeout ***
```

`*** Faking timeout ***` means that popup must be closed, but it doesn't.
Maybe it's because of threading
Help, please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter error on python 3 (RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different appartment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008443/tkinter-error-on-python-3-runtimeerror-calling-tcl-from-different-appartment)

Comment: @Karthik I think no because it is about Tkinter, not PySimpleGUI. Secondly, there is no explanation, so I don't know how to remove it from threading...

Answer (score 1):

Don't call GUI method of PySimpleGUI/tkinter in another thread.
Use `window.write_event_value` to generate one event and handle it in your event loop.

Revised code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import threading
import time

def thread_reminder(seconds, window):
    count = 0
    while count < seconds :
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(count)
    window.write_event_value('Alarm', "1 minute passed")

layout = [
    [sg.Text('', size=(40, 1))],
    [sg.Text('', size=(30, 2)), sg.Text('Press "Start" button', size=(55, 12), key='-MAIN-')],
    [sg.Button('Start', size=(10,2))],
]
window = sg.Window('APP', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Start':
        threading.Thread(target=thread_reminder, args=(10, window), daemon=True).start()
    elif event == 'Alarm':
        message = values[event]
        sg.popup_auto_close(message)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this:

1. PySimpleGUI provides Popups that close after a given time: `sg.popup_timed('popup_timed')  # Automatically closes sg.popup_auto_close('popup_auto_close')  # Same as PopupTimed` see reference for details: [PySimpleGUI Reference - Popups](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#high-level-api-calls-popups)
2. You create an update interval in your event-loop. The complete loop should look like this:

```
while True:
    event, values = window.Read(timeout = 1000 * 10)  # in milliseconds

    if event in ('__TIMEOUT__',):
        print('timed execution inside event loop')
        ### put you window closing commands here ###

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED,): break
```